# Vue 3 vuelidate how can I update user information without password update?

Tags: vuejs3, vuelidate

I'm using vuelidate 3 for vue 3 composition api.
When I try to update user information without password, $invalid always return true.
For this reason save button is always return true and disabled.

How to update without password?

Below code is template.

```
<q-input
  v-model="editedItem.name"
  label="User Name"
  @blur="v$.name.$touch()"
  :error="v$.name.$error"
  :error-message="v$.name.$errors.length ? v$.name.$errors[0].$message : null"
></q-input>
<q-input
  v-model="editedItem.email"
  label="User email"
  @blur="v$.email.$touch()"
  :error="v$.email.$error"
  :error-message="v$.email.$errors.length ? v$.email.$errors[0].$message : null"
></q-input>
<q-input
  v-model="editedItem.avatar"
  label="User Avatar"
></q-input>
<q-input
  v-model="editedItem.password"
  label="Password"
  type="password"
  @blur="v$.password.$touch()"
  :error="v$.password.$error"
  :error-message="v$.password.$errors.length ? v$.password.$errors[0].$message : null"
></q-input>
<q-input
  v-model="editedItem.password_confirm"
  label="Password Confirm"
  type="password"
  @blur="v$.password_confirm.$touch()"
  :error="v$.password_confirm.$error"
  :error-message="v$.password_confirm.$errors.length ? v$.password_confirm.$errors[0].$message : null"
></q-input>
<q-toggle
  v-model="editedItem.is_active"
  :true-value="1"
  :false-value="0"
  label="Activation"
></q-toggle>
<q-btn
  @click="save()"
  flat
  color="primary"
  label="Save"
  :disabled="v$.$invalid"
></q-btn>
```

Below code is for rules

```
    const rules = {
      name: {
        required
      },
      email: {
        required,
        email
      },
      password: {
        minLength: minLength(6)
      },
      password_confirm: {
        minLength: minLength(6),
        sameAsPassword: sameAs('password')
      }
    }
```

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 0):

I have some mistake that parameter of `sameAs` method was wrong, according to reference of vuelidate site parameter must be password's v-model name not 'password'...OMG

Comment: Could you please amend your post to include the link of your reference?